# How to show a specific panel in another using a method call?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I m using java under netbeans IDE, I created a JFrame that contains two panel the first contains a button the second is empty

I also created a JPanel file that contains some text fields and labels
I want to create a method which will display the JPanel file in the empty panel in the JFrame

My code as below :

```
 public class jpanelTools{

   public static final void ShowPanel(JPanel target, JPanel object){

    target.add(object, new GridBagConstraints());
    target.invalidate();
    target.revalidate();
    target.validate();
    target.repaint();
    target.show();
    object.validate();
    object.repaint();
    object.show();

    }
}
```

My JFrame Button ActionPerformed Code :

```
         jpanelTools.ShowPanel(emptyPanel,new DesignedPanel());
```

the image shows my project :  [image]

nothing happens when I run the JFRAME .

Please Tell me how to do.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't post pictures of your IDE, but instead the relevant text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will allow you to swap panels.

The tutorial has a working example to get you started.